# iBATIS's SqlMapper.Update method is returning -1

Tags: .net, oracle, ibatis

I'm new to Oracle and iBATIS. I have an update procedure in a package in the DB. If I call the `Update` method of an `SqlMapper` object to execute this procedure, the procedure runs properly (I can see the new values in the database).

However, despite the fact that the iBATIS documentation states that the `Update` method should return the number of rows effected by the UPDATE call, the method returns negative one (-1) under all circumstances.

Does anyone know what's wrong? I'm using the .Net iBATIS library.